# How to initialize specific fields in a Go struct

Tags: go

If i had a Go `struct` with a long list of fields. Is there a built-in way to initialize an instance while providing value for specific fields only?

Comment: See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals

Comment: Yes, Composite Literals was what I was looking for! If you want to put it as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to write `structType{fieldName: value}` !